# Is there a way to make a table collapse in html with inline css?

Tags: html, css, outlook

Let me start by saying that I'm not an HTML developer. I have been asked to automate an email report with html. It consists of a row with just a person's name, followed by several rows with information about them, for every person in the project. This was pretty easy, but it could look a lot better if I was able to collapse the table by name, so that initially, the viewer would just see a list of names, which, when clicked, would expand to show the other rows. Every one is using Outlook, which has a very limited html engine, if I understand correctly. Is what I'm looking for even possible, given the way outlook handles html? Below, you'll see the structure of the table. Essentially, I'd like to be able to click "Jane Doe", and expose all subsequent rows until the next name.

**HTML:**

```
<table style="width:1000px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #efefef; padding:15px 10px 15px 10px;">
  <tr style="border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;">
    <th align="left" bgcolor="#e7e7e7" style="border: 1px solid #e7e7e7; padding:15px 10px 15px 10px;">
      <font color=black face="Verdana" style="font-size:15px">Jane Doe
      </font>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;">
    <th align="left" bgcolor="#e7e7e7" style="border: 1px solid #e7e7e7; padding:15px 10px 15px 10px;">
      <font color=black face="Verdana" style="font-size:15px">Issue Number
      </font>
    </th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="#e7e7e7" style="border: 1px solid #e7e7e7; padding:15px 10px 15px 10px;">
      <font color=black face="Verdana" style="font-size:15px">Assignee
      </font>
    </th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="#e7e7e7" style="border: 1px solid #e7e7e7; padding:15px 10px 15px 10px;">
      <font color=black face="Verdana" style="font-size:15px">Description
      </font>
    </th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="#e7e7e7" style="border: 1px solid #e7e7e7; padding:15px 10px 15px 10px;">
      <font color=black face="Verdana" style="font-size:15px">Original Estimate
      </font>
    </th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="#e7e7e7" style="border: 1px solid #e7e7e7; padding:15px 10px 15px 10px;">
      <font color=black face="Verdana" style="font-size:15px">Time Logged
      </font>
    </th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="#e7e7e7" style="border: 1px solid #e7e7e7; padding:15px 10px 15px 10px;">
      <font color=black face="Verdana" style="font-size:15px">Percentage Complete
      </font>
    </th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="#e7e7e7" style="border: 1px solid #e7e7e7; padding:15px 10px 15px 10px;">
      <font color=black face="Verdana" style="font-size:15px">Work Done Yesterday
      </font>
    </th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="#e7e7e7" style="border: 1px solid #e7e7e7; padding:15px 10px 15px 10px;">
      <font color=black face="Verdana" style="font-size:15px">Status
      </font>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you could use javascript or jquery for that..you can hide or show divs using that..

Comment: I saw a little of that when I was googling, but it's my understanding that since its an email, I can't use javascript or jquery. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/CBLWS/94/)??

Comment: Outlook's HTML engine is limited. You will have trouble running anything involving JavaScript or JQuery. IIRC the CSS support is also limited. I can't recall any emails I've received where this has been done.

Comment: @Lal, that would be pretty close to perfect if I could figure out a way to put it in an email.

Comment: @Holf, thats what I've been told. I'm wondering if there is a way to use some inline css that would work.

Comment: @WillMartin do you need to use tables?

Comment: I don't suppose I do. Is there a better way?

Comment: @WillMartin can you post the structure of your table?

Comment: @jmore009 there you go.